# Add messages from user into an array and choose randomly

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Right, so what I want to do is get the last `x` messages (x is defined beforehand) and add every message to an array. Then, I want to randomly choose `y` message or multiple if that's what I want.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 var numbermin = parseInt(min)
const collector1 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: numbermin })
    message.channel.send(`Now add your messages. Remember only the first ${min} will be counted`)
    collector1.on("collect", (m) => {
      var msg1 = m.content
      var msg2 = m.content
      var msg3 = m.content

      let replies = [msg1, msg2, ms3]
```

`min` is the number of messages that were defined before.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbermin = parseInt(min)
const collector1 = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: numbermin })
    message.channel.send(`Now add your messages. Remember only the first ${min} will be counted`)
    collector1.on("collect", (m) => {
      var msg1 = m.content
      var msg2 = m.content
      var msg3 = m.content

      let replies = [msg1, msg2, ms3]
      let response = replies[Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)] //generates a random messages from the table "replies"
      message.channel.send(response) //sends the random message
```

Comment: It doesn't actually send out the random number. Also, I want it to make a table of arrays for the amount of `min`.

Comment: To add to the table in javascript you can use `replies.push(variable)`, and what number do you want to send out?

Comment: Sorry, I meant random message, not a number. Regarding `replies.push(variable)`, I think I should clarify. After the first message is sent. I want it to wait until all the last  `min` messages are sent and then pick a random one from there. `min` could be anywhere from 1 to 10.